# How can I display the remaining time of a Spotify song on my Touch Bar?

Tags: macbook-pro, applescript, spotify

Currently, I'm using BetterTouchTool (BTT) to automate tasks.
I was wanting to make a script that would display the time a song has left (in MM: SS format) as a label on my Touch Bar.

Here's what I tried doing to achieve this goal (have a button set up to trigger this script):

if application "Spotify" is running then
    tell application "Spotify"
        return (duration of current track) - (player position)
    end tell
else
    return ""
end if

It's not giving me the output I was expecting. Does anyone know how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

```
tell application "Spotify" to if running then tell ¬
    (duration of current track) - (player position) ¬
    to return "" & (it div minutes) & ":" & (it mod minutes)

return ""
```

However, on my system, *Spotify* is reporting the track duration's incorrectly in AppleScript.

<sup>**System info:** *AppleScript version:* 2.7  *System version:* 10.13.6</sup>

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me:

```
tell application "Spotify" to if running then
    set song_duration to (duration of current track) / 1000
    set song_duration_minutes to song_duration div minutes
    set song_duration_seconds to song_duration mod minutes div 1
    -- pad with 0 if necessary 
    if (count of ("" & song_duration_seconds)) is 1 then
        set song_duration_seconds to "0" & song_duration_seconds
    end if
    set player_position_minutes to (player position) div minutes
    set player_postition_seconds to (player position) mod minutes div 1
    -- pad with 0 if necessary
    if (count of ("" & player_postition_seconds)) is 1 then
        set player_postition_seconds to "0" & player_postition_seconds
    end if
    return "" & player_position_minutes & ":" & player_postition_seconds & "/" & song_duration_minutes & ¬
        ":" & song_duration_seconds
else
    return ""
end if
```

It will display
`"1:43/3:31"`

The song duration is returned in milliseconds, so to get minutes you first need to divide by 1000 to get seconds, then divide by `minutes` to get minutes. For the seconds, it will gives fractions of a second, so I addd `div 1` to convert it to an int (whole number, no fractions). `player position` is in seconds, so it's easier.